# Android ListView Adapter shows only last element

Tags: android, listview

I have a little problem with getting all data from `SQLite` database and showing them in `ListView`. The code I'm using is showing only the last item. Here is the code which I'm using :

```
        ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.saved_codes_listview);
        SystemDatabaseHelper systemDbHelper = new SystemDatabaseHelper(this, null, 1);
        systemDbHelper.initialize(this);

        String sqlQuery = "SELECT code_id, code_string FROM saved_codes";
        Cursor cursor = systemDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
        if(cursor.getCount()==0){
            Log.i("No Saved Codes","There is no Saved Codes.");
        } else if(cursor.getCount()>0){
            for(cursor.move(0); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()){
                String codeString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("code_string"));
                ArrayList<String> codes = new ArrayList<String>();
                codes.add(codeString);
                Log.i("Code String","Code String : "+codeString);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, codes);
                lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
```

I have 3 entries in my database as an example : shosho, bosho, gosho and as a result I have only gosho in my listview. Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code so that you initialize array list before for loop, and also set ArrayAdapter AFTER the loop.

```
ArrayList<String> codes = new ArrayList<String>();
for(cursor.move(0); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()){
                String codeString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("code_string"));
                codes.add(codeString);
                Log.i("Code String","Code String : "+codeString);         
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, codes);
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can I use a custom layout with this code? Instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` use `R.layout.savedCodes_layout` ?

Comment: generally, you can't add custom layout to ArrayAdapter in the way you wrote it, UNLESS your savedCodes_layout contains only one TextView.
You can, however, extend ArrayAdapter class to suit your needs and set it any layout you want.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
            ArrayList<String> codes = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(cursor.move(0); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()){
            String codeString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("code_string"));

            codes.add(codeString);
            Log.i("Code String","Code String : "+codeString);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, codes);
            lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

You re-create a new `ArrayList<String> codes` in every loop so the last loop the list containing only one element, which is the last.

Answer (score 0):

Change   `for(cursor.move(0); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast())`

to `for(cursor.move(0);; cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())`

or use

```
while(cursor.isAfterLast())
cursor.moveToNext();
```